# how to add foreign key in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, foreign-keys

i try to add foreign key but iam getting error "ALTER TABLE Transactions ADD CONSTRAINT
-- Result: near "CONSTRAINT": syntax error"
here is my script, whats wrong whith my script?

```
CREATE TABLE if not EXISTS User(
RekeningID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
NamaBank varchar(10) NOT NULL,
AtasNama varchar(15) NOT NULL,
NomerRekening INT(15) NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Transactions(
UangMasukID Integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
TerimaDari varChar(20) NOT NULL,
Keterangan varChar(100) NOT NULL,
Jumlah int(9) NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE Transactions ADD CONSTRAINT FK_REK(rekID) FOREIGN KEY (rekID) 
REFERENCES User(RekeningID);
```

Comment: That's not valid syntax for sqlite's ALTER TABLE: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html

Comment: Include foreign keys in CREATE TABLE statements: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html

Comment: You should also read https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html

Comment: This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title.